# Scala: get data from scylla using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, datastax, scylla

scala/spark newbie here. I have inherited an old code which I have refactored and been trying to use in order to retrieve data from Scylla. The code looks like:

```
val TEST_QUERY = s"SELECT user_id FROM test_table WHERE name = ? AND id_type = 'test_type';"

var selectData = List[Row]()
dataRdd.foreachPartition {
  iter => {
    // Build up a cluster that we can connect to
    // Start a session with the cluster by connecting to it.
    val cluster = ScyllaConnector.getCluster(clusterIpString, scyllaPreferredDc, scyllaUsername, scyllaPassword)
    var batchCounter = 0

    val session = cluster.connect(tableConfig.keySpace)
    val preparedStatement: PreparedStatement = session.prepare(TEST_QUERY)

    iter.foreach {
      case (test_name: String) => {
        // Get results
        val testResults = session.execute(preparedStatement.bind(test_name))
        if (testResults != null){
          val testResult = testResults.one()
          if(testResult != null){
            val user_id = testResult.getString("user_id")
            selectData ::= Row(user_id, test_name)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    session.close()
    cluster.close()
  }
}

println("Head is =======> ")
println(selectData.head)
```

The above does not return any data and fails with null pointer exception because the `selectedData` list is empty although there is data in there for sure that matches the select statement. I feel like how I'm doing it is not correct but can't figure out what needs to change in order to get this fixed so any help is much appreciated.

PS: The whole idea of me using a list to keep the results is so that I can use that list to create a dataframe. I'd be grateful if you could point me to the right direction here.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the definition of the [foreachPartition function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#foreachPartition-scala.Function1-), you will see that it's by definition can't return anything because its return type is `void`.

Anyway, it's a very bad way of querying data from Cassandra/Scylla from Spark.  For that exists [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) that should be able to work with Scylla as well because of the protocol compatibility.

To [read a dataframe from Cassandra](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#reading-and-writing-without-a-catalog) just do:

```scala
spark.read
  .format("cassandra")
  .option("keyspace", "ksname")
  .option("table", "tab")
  .load()
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/tree/master/doc) is quite detailed, so just read it.